# Java, Errors with JButton

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to make a Login Form with Java. I Cant get it working.

I have looked all over then internet for how to fix this, I can't find anything.

Code:
LoginFrame.java:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*; 
    public class LoginFrame extends JFrame 
    {
      JPanel pane = new JPanel();
      static JFormattedTextField username = new JFormattedTextField(16);
      static JFormattedTextField password = new JFormattedTextField(16);
      static JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login!");
      static String input[];

      public LoginFrame() throws IOException
      {

        super("Login");
        setSize(300,150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container con = this.getContentPane(); 
        con.add(pane); 

        pane.add(new JLabel("Username"));
        pane.add(username);
        pane.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        pane.add(password);
        pane.add(loginButton);
        @Override
        IEventHandler eHandler = new IEventHandler();
        @Override
        loginButton.addActionListener(eHandler);
        setVisible(true);
      }

      static String[] getInput()
      {
        return input;
      }
    }
```

IEventHandler.java:

```
    import java.awt.event.*;

    class IEventHandler implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        if(e.getSource() == LoginFrame.loginButton){
          LoginFrame.loginButton.setEnabled(false);
          new AuthLIB().authenticate(LoginFrame.getInput());
        }
      }
      public IEventHandler()
      {
        System.out.println("Event Handler Hooked");
      }
    }
```

[image: My Errors]

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting errors? If so, please post them.

Comment: They are posted in the link its a image

Comment: So you know, we prefer error logs to be supplied in the form of text, not images, so that readers may copy and paste them. Please copy and paste these things to a pre-formatted block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't overriding anything with-in the method body. These

```
@Override
IEventHandler eHandler = new IEventHandler();
@Override
loginButton.addActionListener(eHandler);
```

should just be

```
IEventHandler eHandler = new IEventHandler();
loginButton.addActionListener(eHandler);
```

**and** assuming you want [`ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29)

```
public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e)
```

should use that annotation. You'd see the spelling mistake quicker anyway.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

Comment: @ComputerCandy: if this worked for you, please consider accepting it as an answer. To do that, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so that it turns green.